# Как сортировать и вывести в список места по возрастанию смотря на дистанцию от геопозиции пользователя на python с помощью geopy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

У меня есть словарь в котором координаты различных мест:

```
STORES: Tuple[dict, ...] = (
    {'title': 'Besh Yogʻoch Savdo',
     'lons': '41.304679',
     'lats': '69.247453',
     'address': 'Oziq-ovqat'},

    {'title': 'Бахт: колбасы и деликатесы',
     'lons': '41.293083',
     'lats': '69.212116',
     'address': 'Oziq-ovqat'},

    {'title': 'Eco - mini market',
     'lons': '41.305242',
     'lats': '69.235547',
     'address': 'Oziq-ovqat'},
)
```

И обработчик принятого местоположения от пользователя телеграм:

```
def uz_shop_view(message: telebot.types.Message):
  if message.location is not None:
      lon: float = message.location.longitude
      lat: float = message.location.latitude

      distance: List[...] = []
      for loc in STORES:
          result: float = geodesic(
              (loc['lons'], loc['lats']), (lon, lat)).meters
          distance.append(result)
      index = distance.index(min(distance))
      bot.send_venue(message.chat.id,
                     STORES[index]['lons'],
                     STORES[index]['lats'],
                     STORES[index]['title'],
                     STORES[index]['address'])
  elif message.location is None:
    bot.reply_to(message, "Отправь местоположение!")
```

И вот вопрос:

Как сделать так чтобы тг бот после получения геопозиции отправил в ответ все места списком из словаря отсортировав его в порядке возрастания смотря на расстояние от него?

библиотека: telebot, geopy

Answer (score 0):

Расстояние я планирую оценивать по формуле a = sin(Deltalat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(Deltalon/2)**2

```
lon1: float = message.location.longitude
lat1: float = message.location.latitude
result = []
for shop in stories:
   lat2 = shop["lats"]
   lon2 = shop["lons"]
   dlon = lon2 - lon1 
   dlat = lat2 - lat1 
   alpha = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2 #Угол между точками
   distance = 2 * asin(sqrt(alpha)) 
   result.append(
    {'title': shop["title"],
     'lons': shop["lons"],
     'lats': shop["lats"],
     'address': shop["address"],
     'distance': distance
}
```

Теперь мы получили массив словариков result. Отсортируем его при помощи lambda функции

```
result = sorted(result, key=lambda k: k['distance'])
```

Теперь отправим его пользователю

```
bot.send_venue(message.chat.id,
                     result['lons'],
                     result['lats'],
                     result['title'],
                     result['address'],
)
```